# Remote debugging ASP.NET Core on a Linux server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

How do I attach the Visual Studio debugger to an ASP.NET Core application running on an [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) server?

I really need to step through my code on the server to see what is going on. Is that possible yet?

Answer (score 10):

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/01/26/debugging-net-core-on-unix-over-ssh/) from Microsoft shows that this is certainly possible. You will be debugging the process over SSH.

You will need minimum the 1/27/2017 update (RC3) for Visual Studio 2017 RC. Also, you need to install a few utilities like `openssh-server`, `unzip` and `curl` on your server.

Then you can deploy a debug release to the your Ubuntu server. The Linux debugger needs [Portable PDBs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs) to be enabled (which is the default).

Attach the debugger and select SSH as the connection type.

Change *Connection Target* to the IP address of the Ubuntu server.

Select the required process (dotnet) to debug and click "Attach".

You will get a dialog to select which type of code you would like to debug. Pick *Managed (.NET Core for Unix)*.

It should enable you to start debugging the ASP.NET Core app deployed on Ubuntu.

Comment: It seems that the blog post [has moved](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/debugging-asp-core-on-linux-with-visual-studio-2017/).
A dependency not mentioned here is to have the dotnet SDK installed (runtime is apparently not enough...)

Comment: Appears things have changed again as [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019) says the SDK is not required.